# Помогите распознать алгоритм, Как называется?

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, распознавание-образов

Науч. Рук говорит что тот алгоритм который он мне дал называется isodata, но в книге это совсем дургой алгоритм, вот сам алгоритм (который дали):

T: (x,y,m - метка) точка с координатами и меткой. инициализируются с m = 0;
D(T_i, T_j) - функция расстояния, например Евклидова мера
D_p - пороговое значение расстояния - параметр алгоритма

```
Кол-во кластеров K = 0
for i to N = кол-во точек do 
    if P_i.m != 0 : continue
    T_0 := T_i, K++, T_0.m = K;
    D_min = max_double;
    for j to N do
        if i = j || T_j.m != 0 then: continue
        D_j = D(T_i, T_j)
        if D_j < D_min then:
            D_min := D_j
            T_min := T_j
    if D_min < D_p then
        T_min.m := T_i.m
        T_0 := среднее африфметическое для всех T_k: T_k.m = T_i.m
    else continue
```

Алгоритм которыйй он мне дал, как ни странно, не работает. Я его реализовывал полгода назад но уже потерял рабочую реализацию.

Формальным языком:
1) Взять непомеченную точку P_i как основу нового кластера
2) Найти для нее ближайшую точку P_k != P_i из массива, если расстояние D(P_k, P_i) не превышает порогового то пометить точку P_k (и перерасчитав центр кластера повторить шаг 2, в моей реализации), иначе перейти к шагу 1.

Фотки с доски:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

Это алгоритм кластеризации [FOREL](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%AD%D0%BB)

Comment: в Фореле центры перерасчитываются после нахождения, а тут после добавления точки, вот я еще изображения прикреплю